# Mono<Object> being returned instead of Mono<ResponseEntity> when mapping (Java 8)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Trying to practice reactive coding for an API but I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong when using `flatMap()` and `map()` to cast to a `ResponseEntity` object. The error mentions that the code is returning a `Mono<Object>` and cant be cast/transformed into a `Mono<ResponseEntity<>>`.

```
Public Mono<ResponseEntity<?> deleteEndpoint(String someId) {
  return db.existsById(someId).flatMap(exists -> {
    if (!exists) return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    else {
      Mono<Boolean> deletedStuff1 = someFunct();
      Mono<Boolean> deletedStuff2 = anotherFunct();
     
      Mono<Tuple2<Boolean, Boolean>> deletedStuff = Mono.zip(deletedStuff1, deletedStuff2);

      return deletedStuff.then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(NO_CONTENT).build());
    }
  });
}
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: Why would anyone want to help you with code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2):

From `.flatMap()` you must return `Publisher`, not actual object

In this if statement you return `ResponseEntity` instead of `Mono<ResponseEntity>`

So, just wrap it with Mono

```
if (!exists) {
    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build());
} else {
    // ...
```